# Yellow error in Eclipse, but no problems shown

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-luna

[image: Yellow Errors on my project]

I have these weird yellow symbols next to my eclipse project. It is under every java file, but when I open the file, I see no errors. Also, I see no problems displayed when I go to Window-> Show View ->Problems. What does this mean?

Comment: are you using any Version Control Management (like svn, git, cvs)?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.

Comment: You are asking for VCM symbol! Check this: http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/tutorials/egit-tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you use **version control plug-in** inside Eclipse IDE like this:
[image]

(Read more about popular version control plug-in: [Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/), [EGit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/))